# C# MDI ограничить появление дочерних форм

Tags: c#

Есть родительская форма **MainForm**, и 2 дочерние формы: 1 - *StudentsTable* и 2 - *TeacherTable*. Открыть только по каждому экземпляра (т.е. чтоб не была сколько угодно открывать). Если тот же существует дочерняя форма, то тогда кнопка со значением Enabled = false;. После закрытия дочернего формы кнопка должна быть Enabled = true;
Пример кода:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StudentsTable form = new StudentsTable()
        {
            MdiParent = this
        };
        form.Show();
        if (form!=null)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Не получается, как можно реализовать...
Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;

    StudentsTable form = new StudentsTable() { MdiParent = this };

    Action <object, EventArgs> closed = () =>
    {
        form.Closed -= WhenClosed;
        button1.Enabled = true;
    };

    form.Closed += closed;
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: Надеюсь, отписка работает...